# How can I calculate business date and time from date assigned in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

For example we have date 5/4/2017 01:00:00 PM And we have working hours 08:00 to 17:30 in weekdays How should I calculate SLA Date and Time ?

Date Assigned :5/4/2017 01:00:00 PM

If SLA is 8  Hours from date assigned .

The Expiry Date should be Like : 5/5/2017 11:30:00 AM by excluding weekends and non-business hours.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure. For what does SLA stand? Cant you just use the `DateTimeAddHours`method?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom  SLA = Service Level Agreement.  In this case, it would refer to the amount of time they have agreed to provide a response by.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you for the info :) But for me it's still not clear what do you mean with "Date Assigned".

Comment: What level do you want to see this at?  To the hour, minute, second?

Answer (score 1):

This is a much more complicated problem then I think you are giving it credit for.  There are a number of days and times that will fall outside of working hours that you will need to take into account.  This will include any holidays, half-days, office closures, etc.  This is best dealt with by maintaining a table of dates, hours or even minutes that are considered *working time*.

If you don't want a table just for this, a simple `Dates` table coupled with a second table of rules of when a particular date or time is considered *working time* or not will allow you to derive this.

If you don't even have that, you will need to derive your table each time you want to run your query and include ***all*** of your *working time* rules within this query.  The most efficient way to create a table of `datetime` values is a Tally Table, which in your case can be utilised as follows:

```sql
declare @DateAssigned datetime = '05-04-2017 13:00:00';
declare @DayStart time = '08:00:00';
declare @DayEnd time = '17:30:00';
declare @SLAMinutes int = 480; -- 8 hours * 60 minutes per hour


       -- cte to create a table with 10 rows in
with n(n) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)
       -- cte to cross join the rows together, resulting in 10^6 (1 million) rows.  Add or remove joins per number of minutes required.
       -- Use the row_number function to add an incremental number of minutes to the original @DateAssigned to get a table of minutes from the @DateAssigned value.
    ,t(t) as (select dateadd(minute,row_number() over(order by (select null))-1,@DateAssigned) from n n1, n n2, n n3, n n4, n n5, n n6)
       -- Select the first @SLANumber number of rows that meet your Working Time criteria.  We add 2 to this value do resolve the fencepost problem.
    ,d(d) as (select top (@SLAMinutes + 2) t
              from t
              where cast(t as time) >= @DayStart      -- Only return minutes from 08:00 onwards.
                and cast(t as time) <= @DayEnd        -- Only return minutes up to 17:30.
                and datepart(weekday,t) not in (7,1)  -- Only return minutes not on Saturday or Sunday.
              order by t)
  -- The MAX value in the cte d will be the last minute of your SLA window.
select @DateAssigned as DateAssigned
      ,max(d) as SLADeadline
from d;
```

Which Outputs:

```sql
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|      DateAssigned       |       SLADeadline       |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-05-04 13:00:00.000 | 2017-05-05 11:30:00.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```