# Calculate Expected End Time In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a SLA Policy as follow:
Working Days: Monday To Friday.
Working Hours: 9 AM To 6 PM.

Apart from them, other working hours are considered as After Business Hours.
Saturday, Sunday and Holidays are excluded from all calculations.

Scenario 1: Ticket is create as Friday, June 29, 2018, 17:30 (5:30 PM). After Working Hours duration is 12 Hours (OR 720 Minute).
I want to calculate, expected end date, Which would be approximately Monday, July 02, 2018 6 AM, because after 6 pm from June 29 upto 11:59 PM, it's after Business Hours and on Monday from 12 AM to 6 AM, it's after Business Hours.

Scenario 2: If it would be 18 hours for after Business Hours, then approximately end date would be Monday, July 02, 21:00 Hrs (9 PM). 6 hours (of June 29) + 9 Hours (July 02 Morning) + 3 Hours (July 2 Night).

How do I calculate after business hours in calculation for expected end date and time in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, he's just here to get an answer, leave with it and coming back under another nickname.

Comment: @SnakeFoot -  I have tried using Time calculations as shown in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776584/how-can-i-calculate-business-date-and-time-from-date-assigned-in-sql). It works fine for normal shift configuration from 9 AM to 6 PM. I want to create outside business hours expected finish date and time.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, I've been doing something similar - and you might want to consider creating a holiday table...

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME = '2018-06-01', 
        @d2 DATETIME = '2018-06-04'

SELECT Datediff(dd, @d1, @d2) 
      + CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, @d1) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       - (Datediff(wk, @d1, @d2) * 2 ) 
       - CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, @d1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       - CASE WHEN Datepart(dw, @d2) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END AS DaysBetween
```

Comment: This is not considering remaining time of the day after ticket is created for calculating total after business hours. Number of days is not required. Actual expected date and time is required.

Comment: No, but it does show you how to avoid counting the weekends.
You would need to combine it with something like...

`Declare @DT as Datetime = '2018-06-29 17:30:00'`
`Select @DT, DATEADD(MINUTE, 720, @DT) as Later`